# Match expression across multiple lines in shell script

Tags: regex, shell, scripting, grep

I wish to match a pattern across multiple lines in a shell script. My input is as:

```
START <some data including white spaces>
<some data including white spaces, can span across multiple lines, number of lines are variable>
ID: n1 <some data including white spaces>
<some data including white spaces, can span across multiple lines, number of lines are variable>
END

START <some data including white spaces>
<some data including white spaces, can span across multiple lines, number of lines are variable>
ID: n2 <some data including white spaces>
<some data including white spaces, can span across multiple lines, number of lines are variable>
END
```

I am trying to display the output using regex for a specific ID only (eg. n1 or n2). I tried `START(.|\n)*ID: n1(.|\n)*END` regex but it fetches the data of ID: n2 as well. What changes should I make to the regex inorder to get data of only the specific ID?

I am using `cat inputfile | grep 'pattern' > outputfile` as the command.

The number of lines in each block as well as the number of lines between `START` and `ID: n1`, `ID: n1` and `END` can be variable and hence using head/tail is not a viable option. Also, I would like to print the whole block from START to END when the ID is matched.

EDIT: I tried using an [Online Regex Creator](http://regexr.com/) and it could successfully match the regex

`START[\s\S][^END]*ID: n1[\s\S][^END]*END`

on my input file.

Comment: Is Perl acceptable? Easy in Perl...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ***GNU* `awk` or *Mawk* solution** that can handle any number of lines, including empty ones, between paired `START` and `END` occurrences:

```
awk -v id='n2' -v RS='(^|\n)START |\nEND' '
  $0 ~ ("\nID: " id " ") { print "START " $0 "\nEND" }
' file
```

<sup>This solution uses a multi-character `RS` value (that is also a regex), which is not supported in the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html). Both GNU `awk` and [Mawk](http://invisible-island.net/mawk/) (the default `awk` on Ubuntu) support such values, however, whereas BSD/macOS `awk` does not.</sup>

- `-v id='n2'` passes ID value `n2` as variable `id` to Awk.
- `RS='(^|\n)START |\nEND'` breaks the input into records by (line-spanning) text between tokens `START`  at the start of the input / a line and token `END` after a newline.
- `$0 ~ ("\nID: " id " ")` matches each input record (`$0`) against a regex (`~`) that matches the specified ID: a newline followed by `ID:` , followed by the ID value of interest (stored in variable `id`) and a space.
  Note how string concatenation in Awk works by simply placing strings / variable references next to each other.
- In case of a match, `print "START " $0 "\nEND"` prints the input record at hand, bookended by the `START` and `END` tokens (which, as the input record separators, doesn't report as part of `$0`).

---

***If* the lines between paired `START` and `END` occurrences are all *nonempty*** (i.e., contain at least 1 char., even if that char. is a space or tab), here's a **POSIX-compliant `awk`** solution:

```
awk -v id='n2' -v RS= '$0 ~ ("\nID: " id " ")' file
```

Note that `-v RS=`, i.e., setting the input record separator (`RS`) to the empty string, is an `awk` idiom that breaks the input into records by *paragraphs* (runs of nonempty lines).

Answer (score 1):

`awk` in paragraph mode, using two successive newlines as record separator:

```
awk -v RS='\n\n' '/ID: n1/' file.txt
```

Replace `n1` with `n2`, `n3`... for others.

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt
START <some data including white spaces>
<some data including white spaces>
ID: n1 <some data including white spaces>
<some data including white spaces>
END

START <some data including white spaces>
<some data including white spaces>
ID: n2 <some data including white spaces>
<some data including white spaces>
END

START <some data including white spaces>
<some data including white spaces>
ID: n3 <some data including white spaces>
<some data including white spaces>
END


$ awk -v RS='\n\n' '/ID: n1/' file.txt
START <some data including white spaces>
<some data including white spaces>
ID: n1 <some data including white spaces>
<some data including white spaces>
END


$ awk -v RS='\n\n' '/ID: n2/' file.txt
START <some data including white spaces>
<some data including white spaces>
ID: n2 <some data including white spaces>
<some data including white spaces>
END


$ awk -v RS='\n\n' '/ID: n3/' file.txt
START <some data including white spaces>
<some data including white spaces>
ID: n3 <some data including white spaces>
<some data including white spaces>
END
```

Comment: The number of lines between `START` and `ID: n1` as well as `ID: n1` and `END` are variable. Hence, using `\n\n` would not yield the required results.

Comment: @ChintanParikh Text-processing is completely dependent on input. Make your input precise please.

Comment: edited the question. And to make it double sure, the number of lines before and after the `ID` are variable. Hence, the block of data is

`START <any characters spanning variable number of lines including white spaces>
ID: n1<any characters spanning variable number of lines including white spaces>
END`.
I hope this erases any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

In `awk` you can accumulate the text between your starting pattern and ending pattern and then test that buffer for your match:

```
cat inputfile | awk  '/^START/        { buf=$0 "\n"; flag=1; next } 
                      flag            { buf=buf $0 "\n" } 
                      /^END/ && flag  { flag=0; if (buf ~ /ID: n1 |ID: n2 /) print buf }'
```

---

In Perl you can do:

```
cat inputfile | perl -0777 -lne 'while (/(^START.*?^ID: (n\d+) .*?^END)/gms){
    if ($2 eq "n1" || $2 eq "n2"){
        print "$1\n\n";
    }
}'
```

---

In either case, you may want to do `awk '{script}' inputfile` or `perl '{script}' inputfile` rather than using `cat`

Comment: I am a novice in Perl but am getting an error while running the code as `String found where expected operator`.

Comment: Does it work on the example? Please update your post with a more relevant example of your actual data.

Comment: The only change I made was that I used `cat inputfile` instead of `echo "$txt"`

Comment: It may be a shell quoting issue on your shell. Are you using Bash? You can try `perl -0777 -e '{perl one liner}' inputfile` vs using `cat`